# Message Lockdown

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, blackberry

I am developing an SMS and QRCode Applications where a QRCode or an SMS will be sent to a user's phone. I don't want them to forward the message to anyone.

1. I want to know if it is possible that when a user receive a message, the message can be locked on his phone so that he cannot forward it to anyone.
2. Is it also possible to prevent a user from editing the message?

Am developing it for Android, IPhone and later for BlackBerry.

Comment: are you sure you even need to tackle this problem? is this something the user will do or a hacker will do, if a hacker actually got the user's phone do you think forwarding would be the concern? nothing would stop the user from copying and pasting even if you locked down SMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No, it's not possible. As a third-party developer you can't control what's done with the SMS store beyond your own application. If they were using your app you could keep them from forwarding it through your application, but there's nothing stopping them from using another.

2) See #1

Even if you could, there's nothing stopping a user from just taking a screenshot of the message and forwarding that.